# Fast NSData unarchiving

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I create `NSData` from a class instance like this:

```
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:db];
[data writeToFile:@"/Users/.../db.data" atomically:true];
```

Then I need to load this instance:

```
NSURL* dbUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"db" withExtension:@"data"];
NSData* dbData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dbUrl];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    self.db = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dbData];
});
```

This loading lasts cca. 6 seconds for ~70MB file size. It is very slow! I tried to separate `db` instance into 2 different parts (~35MB) and load them like this:

```
self.db = [[Database alloc]init];
NSURL* dbUrl1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"db1" withExtension:@"data"];
NSData* dbData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dbUrl1];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    self.db.nodes = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dbData1];
});
NSURL* dbUrl2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"db2" withExtension:@"data"];
NSData* dbData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dbUrl2];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    self.db.trips = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dbData2];
});
```

With this way loading lasts cca. 3 seconds (2x faster). Do you know another ways to load it faster?

**EDIT 1:**

I'm not sure that it can help, but archived object has two `NSMutableArray` instances. The first one contains a lot of `Node` objects:

```
@interface DatabaseNode : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double lat;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double lon;

@end
```

And the second one contains a lot of `Trip` objects:

```
@interface DatabaseTrip : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger service;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* departureTimes; //Contains NSDate

@end
```

Comment: It all depends on the kind of data you are archiving, the frequency with which the archive changes,  and the source of said archive.

Comment: @bbum Yes, it's obvious. The question is how to speed up the "basic" process of unarchiving.

Comment: No, it isn't obvious because the answer is, quite likely, *don't use `NSUnarchiver`*.  But without more contextual information, there is no way anyone here can tell.   Note that "speeding up" by parallelizing often won't actually speed anything up in any kind of predictable fashion.

Comment: Also, you are writing to a path that your read code can never read from (unless your "write" code is a part of your build process).   So, no, still not obvious.

Comment: @bbum I don't see any alternatives for `NSUnarchiver` except `Core Data`. And I know how parallelizing works. I'm asking you about hacks to make my application work faster. Btw code for loading/saving NSData is added just to make code more readable, question is not about this.

Comment: Thanks.  That context helps a lot.  Now, does all that data all have to be in memory at the same time?   And what format are you archiving in (specifically, did you ensure that you are writing a binary format and not XML)?

Comment: @bbum Unfortunately, I need to have all this data in the memory as soon as possible, but `nodes` array I need a bit earlier. Actually, I don't know what format I use, but I can't open result files like XML ones. I use basic NSData's `writeToFile:atomically:` method.

Comment: `archivedDataWithRootObject:`defaults to NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0, which is good for performance, but not so good for you because it isn't fast enough.

You're going to have to move to your own format, most likely.  `NSKeyedArchiver` is optimized to archiving object graphs and, thus, there is quite a bit of overhead related to read/write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need all the data in memory from the beginning of your app's session, you're going to have to go with a solution other than `NSKeyedArchiver`.   NSKA is designed to archive complex object graphs and, thus, is optimized to solve a different problem.

In your case, I'd suggest a build phase that writes the static data to a file format that can be mapped into memory without parsing.  Then, at runtime, map the file and have a pass that turns it into a minimal encapsulation in Foundation types.

For Strings, a string table like solution will work well enough.   Dates can be a little bit trickier, maybe.  I'd test to see if the time interval based creation methods are fast.  If they are, then you can just store your dates as arrays (not NSArrays, but flat C arrays of NSTimeIntervals) in the mapped file and do a fixup pass.

Of course, you may also skip the fixup of some subset of data based on the access patterns in your app.  If your users don't really look at all the dates at once, then there is no need to fix 'em up on load, but they can be created on demand.

Comment: This solution sounds good, I want to try it. Maybe, do you have any links about how to implement it for iOS? I can't find anything.

Comment: I don't, offhand.  I'd look up "architecture agnostic data archival" to start with.